# library javascript owl.carousel.js

Tags: javascript

Hola mi problema con esta biblioteca que no me carga en la primera página, en cambio si "actualizo" si se carga, y el explorador de internet no me funciona. a alguien le ha pasado algo parecido. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal, pongo un enlace y una captura del error. GRACIAS https://ccc.es/empresa/ https://ibb.co/3fXLPyH

```
 <script type = 'text / javascript' src = 'https: //ccc.es/wp-content/themes/norebro/assets/js/libs/owl.carousel.min.js? ver = 5.4.2'> < / script>
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: hola pego el js del complemento por si me podeis ayudar, GRACIAS <script src="https://gist.github.com/ervanecarreno/991ec24d420c231c5c9001942feecb76.js"></script>

Comment: Creo que no me dejé entender, revisa a detalle las sugerencias, te serán de apoyo para conseguir una mayor chance de obtener una respuesta que solucione tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: ok, gracias reviso mi entrada

Answer (score 0):

Hola he encontrado una solución que le ha pasado a otro compañero, lo dejo por aqui.

```js
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!--DO NOT ENTER ANY EXTERNAL LINK IN BETWEEN-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
    });
});
</script>`
```